# Why is command line computed base64 string different than curl computed base64 string?

Tags: http, command-line, curl, base64, basic-authentication

Really confused - Guess it has to do with a single character placement at the end, or possible padding done with basic digest that I'm not aware of..?

So, if I execute this, you can see the product of the base64 encode:

```
echo 'host@mail.com:password' | openssl enc -base64
aG9zdEBtYWlsLmNvbTpwYXNzd29yZAo=
```

Now, if I make a curl request:

```
curl -v -u host@mail.com:password https://
aG9zdEBtYWlsLmNvbTpwYXNzd29yZA==
```

You'll notice that the base64 strings are NOT the same..haha what? The base64 command line one is actually incorrect - if you substitute that in the request, it fails. SO - does basic digest NOT truly use a base64 string? I'm noticing that is always doing a o= instead of == at the end of the string ...

And ideas?

EDIT: So, it was the trailing newline from echo:
       -n     do not output the trailing newline

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> 'aG9zdEBtYWlsLmNvbTpwYXNzd29yZA=='.decode('base64')
'host@mail.com:password'
>>> 'aG9zdEBtYWlsLmNvbTpwYXNzd29yZAo='.decode('base64')
'host@mail.com:password\n'
```

Try `echo -n` instead.

Comment: echo -n "host@mail.com:password" | openssl enc -base64
aG9zdEBtYWlsLmNvbTpwYXNzd29yZA==

...Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: >>> 'aG9zdEBtYWlsLmNvbTpwYXNzd29yZA=='.decode('base64') \ 'host@mail.com:password' ... Looks fine to me...

Comment: DOH - sorry - was comparing it against the actualy user:pass. heh, works great, thanks!